# How do i put the about section under the header but on top of the footer?

Tags: html, css

I want the about section to be under the FIXED header and on top of the footer?
I am struggling how to fix this problem, I tried to add padding to the top but i noticed that it just moves the content not the whole div.Also position relative does not fix the problem as the footer is not under the about section An explanation to the answer will be helpful to understand the answer properly.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 50px
}

header {
  background-color: #191919;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  color: #edf9ff;
  min-height: 70px;
  border-bottom: #0fe216 3px solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top:0;
}

header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #edf9ff;
}
a:hover {
  color:blue;
}

header ul {
  margin: 0;
}

header li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
#showtime {
  position:relative;
  top:100px;
  width:80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
#showtime img {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
}
/*Image Repz*/
.showright {
  clear:both;
}

.highlight {
  font-size:125%;
  color:blue;
}
.showright img {
  float:right;
  clear:both;
}
.boxes:first-child {
  padding-top:50px;
}
.boxes:not(:first-child) {
  padding-top:100px;
  
}
.showright > p, .showright > h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
.showleft img {
  float:left;
  clear:both;
}
.showleft > p, .showleft > h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
footer {
margin-top:30px;
  background-color:#191919;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  clear:both;
}
footer p{
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Photography | Home </title>
        <link href="About.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="Home.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
            <div id="branding">
                <h2>PHOTOGRAPHY</h2>
            </div>
            <nav id="links">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PHOTO GALLERY</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">VIDEO GALLERY</a></li>
            </ul>
                </nav>
        </header>
        <section id="showtime">
                <div class="showleft boxes">
                    <h2>What are we about?</h2>
                    <p>In Mukhtar Photography, we specialise in creating a perfect video with the highest quality and we always tend to keep our promise. Whether it is an
                        Video or not we are <span class="highlight">MASTERS</span> at delivering the best photos
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="showleft boxes">
                    <h2>Why should you ask Mukhtar Photography for like: Marriages, videos?</h2>
                    <p>Because we put our dedication towards and is very unlikely to be any cancels to the project and if there is you will be paid 90% of the money you gave us.
                    </p>
            </div>
        </section>
              
        <footer>
            <p>Note that any copyright &copy; is reserved</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make sure the content is behind the header, you can use "z-index" in css.
To arrange the footer below the content div, you have to make its position "relative".
To get spacing between the content and the footer, you can add a bottom margin to the content div.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 50px
}

header {
  background-color: #191919;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 4;
  width: 100%;
  color: #edf9ff;
  min-height: 70px;
  border-bottom: #0fe216 3px solid;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top:0;
}

header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #edf9ff;
}
a:hover {
  color:blue;
}

header ul {
  margin: 0;
}

header li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
#showtime {
  position:relative;
  top:100px;
  width:80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
#showtime img {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
}
/*Image Repz*/
.showright {
  clear:both;
}

.highlight {
  font-size:125%;
  color:blue;
}
.showright img {
  float:right;
  clear:both;
}
.boxes:first-child {
  padding-top:50px;
}
.boxes:not(:first-child) {
  padding-top:100px;
  
}
.showright > p, .showright > h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
.showleft img {
  float:left;
  clear:both;
}
.showleft > p, .showleft > h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
footer {
  position: relative;
  margin-top:30px;
  background-color:#191919;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  clear:both;
}
footer p{
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Photography | Home </title>
        <link href="About.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="Home.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <header>
            <div id="branding">
                <h2>PHOTOGRAPHY</h2>
            </div>
            <nav id="links">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">PHOTO GALLERY</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">VIDEO GALLERY</a></li>
            </ul>
                </nav>
        </header>
        <section id="showtime">
                <div class="showleft boxes">
                    <h2>What are we about?</h2>
                    <p>In Mukhtar Photography, we specialise in creating a perfect video with the highest quality and we always tend to keep our promise. Whether it is an
                        Video or not we are <span class="highlight">MASTERS</span> at delivering the best photos
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="showleft boxes">
                    <h2>Why should you ask Mukhtar Photography for like: Marriages, videos?</h2>
                    <p>Because we put our dedication towards and is very unlikely to be any cancels to the project and if there is you will be paid 90% of the money you gave us.
                    </p>
            </div>
        </section>
              
        <footer>
            <p>Note that any copyright &copy; is reserved</p>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `z-index` for header. This Will Fix It.

```
header {
    background-color: #191919;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    color: #edf9ff;
    min-height: 70px;
    border-bottom: #0fe216 3px solid;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-top: 0;
    z-index: 99; // ADD THIS LINE
}
```

Comment: Z-index is used for the order under the element. I think